# NMVe SSD Fedora Throughput Tests too High

Tags: performance, disk, ssd, samsung, nvme

I am testing throughput of a Samsung 950 Pro SSD Card which uses NVMe protocol. My current method of testing is to mount a file system on a partition and write a file of size X bytes to the file system. By recording the time it takes to do so, the bytes/second can be calculated.

In my test, I have a while loop that will write up to the X bytes in variable block sizes, one block at a time, specified by a higher level for loop. On top of this, I also have another loop that will run N of these applications in parallel, each application writing to a different partition of the SSD.

Currently, I am seeing speeds slightly faster than the theoretical max transfer speed specified by the Samsung 950 Pro datasheet for both reading and writing. Samsung specified that the max sequential write speed for the 950 Pro is 1.5 GB/s and the max sequential read speed is 2.5 GB/s.

https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-950-pro-nvme-512gb-mz-v5p512bw/#specs

Here is the main function of the bash script that loops through the number of applications to run and block sizes:

```
appInstances=1
while [ $appInstances -le 4 ]
do
    for blocksize in 4096 32768 131072 524288 1048576 67108864 268435456 1073741824
    do
       # Run the test
       datetime
       echo "[$datetime_v]: Test blocksize: $blocksize appInstances: $appInstances"
       run_single_perf_test $blocksize

    done

    appInstances=`expr $appInstances \* 2`

done
exit 0
```

Here is write section of run_perf_test. There is also a read section after this part, which comprises the writing throughput speed test. Between the tests, I unmount all partitions of the SSD and remount them to allow all NVMe transactions to complete and prevent any caching from writing operations to influence the throughput measurement for the reading operation.

```
instCnt=1
childpids=""
while [ $instCnt -le $appInstances ]
do
fsrw -w $blocksize /fsmnt/fs${instCnt}/usernumber1/j.j &

# Save the process ID
childpids="$childpids $!"

# Increment the instace count.
instCnt=`expr $instCnt + 1`
done
```

fsrw is a C++ application that based on the first argument, "-r" or "-w", the second argument, the block size, and the third argument, the filename which is a file on the SSD partition, will build a string and attempt to open the file on the SSD partition and write the string to it. Here is the implementation for the write function, which is called when "-w" is provided as the first argument.

```
/*! \fn perform_writeop()
 *  \brief The function returns true when the write operation completes successfully. 
 *
 *  The function will run until the read is complete or a 35 second timeout is reached.
 *  It will record the time before the write begins, then also record the time afterward.
 *  If the timeout is reached this should be about 35 seconds
 */
bool perform_writeop ()
{
    // File descriptor.
    int32_t fd = -1;

    // Function status.
    bool status = false;

    // Zero writes
    int zero_writes = 0;

    // Buffer fill index.
    int32_t bfidx = 0;

    // Character value.
    int8_t cv = 33;

    // Fill the buffer with printable characters.
    for (; bfidx < blocksize; bfidx++, cv++)
    {
        // Verify the character value is in range.
        if (cv >= 127)
        {
            cv = 33;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add to the buffer.
            buf[bfidx] = cv;
        }
    }

    // Open the file.
    fd = open (fname.c_str (), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0660);

    // Verify the file has been opened.
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        cout << get_datetime_string() << "Write open of " << fname 
        << " failed.  Errno: " << errno << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Total bytes written.
        uint64_t written = 0;

        // Notify the start of the test.
        cout << get_datetime_string() << "Write test started" << endl;

        // Elapsed time.
        struct timeval tv = { 0 };
        get_elapsed_time (&tv);
        struct timeval write_tv = tv;

        // Run until it is time for the test to stop.
        while (written < READ_LIMIT && zero_writes < 10)
        {
            ssize_t writesize = write (fd, &buf[0], blocksize);
            if (writesize == -1)
            {
                cout << get_datetime_string << "Write failure.  Errno: " << errno << endl;
                zero_writes = 10;
            }
            else if (0 == writesize)
            {
                cout << get_datetime_string() << "Zero bytes written" << endl;
                zero_writes++;
            }
            else
            {
                written += writesize;
            }
        }

    string flush_command = "nvme flush /dev/nvme0n1p";
    flush_command += fname[9];
    system(flush_command.c_str());


    // Get the elapsed time.
    get_elapsed_time (&write_tv);

    // Report the number of bytes written.
    cout << get_datetime_string() << "Write " << written << " bytes in "
     << write_tv.tv_sec << "." << write_tv.tv_usec
     << " seconds" << endl;

    // Close the file.
    close (fd);

    // Get the elapsed time.
    get_elapsed_time (&tv);

    // Report the number of bytes read.
    cout << get_datetime_string() << "Write closed.  " << written 
    << " Bytes written in " << tv.tv_sec << "." << tv.tv_usec 
    << " seconds" << endl;

    // Report the number of bytes per second.
    cout << get_datetime_string() << "Bytes per second " 
    << bytes_per_second (&tv, written) << endl;

    // Report the cache flush time.
    struct timeval flush_tv = { 0 };
    timersub (&tv, &write_tv, &flush_tv);
    cout << get_datetime_string() << "System cache flush completed in " 
    << flush_tv.tv_sec << "." << flush_tv.tv_usec << "seconds" << endl;

    // Set the function return status when all write operations have
    // been successful.
    if (zero_writes < 10)
    {
      status = true;
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```

The data I am getting back looks like this
[image]

The numbers are close to the maximum theoretical throughputs of the Samsung 950 Pro but some are too high and this troubles me. Why might I be getting numbers higher than the theoretical maximum throughput for the Samsung 950 Pro?